# Problem with gmailfs

Tags: linux, email, drive

I've got a little with gmailfs.

I'm trying to mount gmail accout as a local file system on my Debian Lenny using the following command.

```
mount -t gmailfs none /mnt/gmail -o username=gmail_username@gmail.com,password=mypassword,fsname=SixSixSix
```

But it gives my garbage like this

```
Ignored option :rw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sbin/mount.gmailfs", line 166, in <module>
    main(mountpoint, namedOptions, useEncfs)
  File "/sbin/mount.gmailfs", line 92, in main
    gmailfs.main(mountpoint, namedOptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gmailfs.py", line 1175, in main
    server = Gmailfs(namedOptions,mountpoint,version="gmailfs 0.8.0",usage='',dash_s_do='setsingle')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gmailfs.py", line 611, in __init__
    self.ga.login()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/libgmail.py", line 316, in login
    raise GmailLoginFailure("Login failed. (Wrong username/password?)")
libgmail.GmailLoginFailure: 'Login failed. (Wrong username/password?)'
```

Username and Password are totally correct.

Answer (score 3):

This is posted on the gmailfs website:

"Gmail Filesystem no longer works with the latest Gmail interface, and will not be maintained in the future."

[Gmail Filesystem](http://richard.jones.name/google-hacks/gmail-filesystem/gmail-filesystem.html)

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://home.comcast.net/~anton.solovyev//hacks/

It's a revised version of libgmail that apparently (I've not tested it) works with the latest Google changes.

(I'm the original creator of libgmail but no longer maintain it.)